# Appscript to attach multiple pdfs from Google drive to Gmail - All pdfs look the same on mobile

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, gmail, gmail-api

This is a weird one.

I'm using google sheets and appscript to export invoices from google drive and email them to my clients. So some clients have multiple invoices that need to be attached to the same email. I have it working, and the attachments look right in my sent mail, and even when the recipient downloads them and opens them on their computer they seem  correct. But when opened on mobile the pdfs all appear to be the same attachment. I can solve this by forwarding the exact same email from my sent mail to the same client, and all of a sudden it works on mobile. All I'm doing is forwarding the exact same email with the exact same attachments to the same client, and it works. I can't make sense of it.

This doesn't seem to be an issue with mobile OS's, or mobile apps, it's happening to all clients, and when I forward back the same email, it works on mobile. I just can't seem to narrow down where the issue would be. Here's my code:

```
function createDraft() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  // get the list of clients
  var clientSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Clients");
  var rangeData = clientSheet.getDataRange();
  var lastRow = rangeData.getLastRow() - 1;
  var clientNameValues = clientSheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow, 5).getValues();

  // get the root invoice folder
  var invoiceFolderId = [FOLDER_ID];
  var invoiceFolder=DriveApp.getFolderById(invoiceFolderId);
  
  // check if date folder exists, and if not throw an error
  if (folderExists(dateFolderName, invoiceFolderId) === false) {
    // add error
  }
  
  //get current date folder name
  var invoiceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Invoice");
  var dateFolderName = invoiceSheet.getRange(9, 6).getValue()
  var monthOutput = invoiceSheet.getRange(10, 6).getValue()
  var yearOutput = invoiceSheet.getRange(11, 6).getValue()
  var payDate = invoiceSheet.getRange(12, 6).getValue()
  
  //get the date folder ID
  var dateFolderId = invoiceFolder.getFoldersByName(dateFolderName).next().getId();
  var clientFolders=DriveApp.getFolderById(dateFolderId).getFolders();
  
  var fileArray = []
  

  // loop through client folders
  while(clientFolders.hasNext()) {
    var clientEmail = ''
    var dir = clientFolders.next();
    var clientFolderName = dir.getName()
    for(nn=0;nn<lastRow;++nn){
      if (clientNameValues[nn][0]==clientFolderName){
        clientEmail = clientNameValues[nn][4]
      };
    }

    
    var files = dir.getFiles();
    var j = 0;
    
    //loop through files
    while(files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      fileArray[j] = file.getAs(MimeType.PDF);

      j++;
    }
    
    GmailApp.createDraft(clientEmail, 'Customer Statement - ' + clientFolderName , 'Your customer statement(s) for ' + monthOutput + ' ' + yearOutput + ' is attached. \n' + 'Payment will be deposited into your account on ' + monthOutput + ' ' + payDate + ', '  + yearOutput + '.', {
      attachments: fileArray,
      name: '[ALIAS_NAME]',
      from: '[ALIAS_EMAIL]'
    });
    fileArray = []
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `This doesn't seem to be an issue with mobile OS's, or mobile apps, it's happening to all clients` if the previous statement is stated that `But when opened on mobile the pdfs all appear to be the same attachment`?

Comment: Well it must be related, but I think the issue is with the way appscript is attaching the files. Because when I forward the same email a 2nd time, it works.

Comment: But the issue with the first email only replicates on the mobile apps right? Is it happening all the time, or it does not happen with different documents attached?

Comment: It happens every time I run this script, which is monthly. And it is different documents every time.

Comment: But after running the script the first time, on a web client it shows as it should and only fails on mobile clients right?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Answer (score 0):

Since the issue does happen on the mobile version, I would suggest reporting it from the Send Feedback channel.

On the Gmail mobile app go to the burger menu on the left, under Settings
click `Help & feedback`. Then at the bottom click `Send feedback`

**Update**

> Have you had a look through my code though to see if there could be any issues with the way app script is attaching the files and sending the email?

Yes I have tested it modifying it a bit in order to be able to send the email because the folder structure required for your script  is not shared, but the script sends the file and it shows with no issue on the web UI and on the Gmail app.

The only thing I could mention is that you are creating a draft and not actually sending the mail, you could fix this by adding a `.send()` at the end like:

```
GmailApp.createDraft('Email', 'Customer Statement+', "body" , {
    attachments: fileArray
  }).send();
```

Comment: Have you had a look through my code though to see if there could be any issues with the way app script is attaching the files and sending the email?